# Three loops complexity

Tags: c, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

Can anyone tell me the complexity of the below code and explain the calculations?

```
int count=0;
for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
    for(int j=i; j<n;j++)
        for(int k=j;k>i;k--)
            count++;
```

Thanks

Comment: Can they? Yes, but it wouldn't be appropriate for them to do so on this website. (People don't like being asked to do homework for other people here)

Comment: I'm not asking anyone to do homework, I simply need some assistance

Comment: It sure feels like homework. Here's a tip: count the number of nested loops. It's essential to figuring out the answer.

Comment: intuition says it would be n^3.

Comment: Well, I did try to count and actually ran some testing by printing i j k and the counter, for n=4 counter is 10, for n=5 counter is 20 and for n=10 counter is 165.
It is definitely less than n^3, its just that for some reason, the third loop looks less than n to me... any advice?

Comment: _"It is definitely less than n^3"_ It's not.

Comment: https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/ should give you the assistance you need.

Comment: Three nested loops means O(N^3) unless it turns out that one of the loops has a bound that grows slower than N. Since the conditions are a bit fiddly you need to verify that.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a "simple" math:

for first loop, its quite straightforward, it will do `n` iterations.

Second loop is not that much more complicated:

- `i=0`: you will have `n` iterations.
- `i=1`: `n-1` iterations
- `i=2`: `n-2` iterations
- `...`
- `i=n-1`: `1` iteration

Sum of it is `n(n+1)/2`.

For third loop, we are only interested when `j>i`:

- `i=n-1`: you have `0` iteration.
- `i=n-2`: `1` iteration, and that is when `j=n-1`
- `i=n-3`: `2` iteration when `j=n-1` and `1` iteration when `j=n-2`
- `i=n-4`: `3` iteration when `j=n-1`, `2` iteration when `j=n-2`, `1` iteration when `j=n-3`
- `...`
- `i=0`: `n-1` iteration when `j=n-1`, `n-2` iteration when `j=2`, ..., `1` iteration when `j=1`

Running time of this is:

```
O((n-1)n/2 + (n-2)(n-1)/2+...+(n-n+2)(n-n+1)/2+(n-n+1)(n-n)/2)=O((n-1)*(n^2)/2)=O(n^3)
```